# What is the opposite of :checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, checkbox

I have a jquery script like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            if ($('#type_seller_correction').is(":unchecked")) // check if the checkbox is not checked
            {
                console.log("unchecked");
            }
});
```

But this does not work because `:unchecked` is wrong.

And I don't know what is the opposite of `:checked` in this situation.

So how can I check if the checkbox is unchecked?

Comment: You can use not checked e.g
$(":checkbox:not(:checked)")